# evaluate Integral using hypergeometric function (how to get to 2F1)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, parametric, hypergeometric-function

How "step by step" evaluate the following integral to the hypergeometric Guassian form 2F1.
$$\int \frac{(a-be^{-ct})^{\alpha-1}} {e^{t(\alpha-1)(g+f)}} dt $$
**where:**
 **$\alpha$**  $\;$  is a parameter from 0 to 1
a, b, c, f, g  $\;$  are parameters, real positive.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.